# Thread local variable accessed through non-thread local object

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, thread-local

Let's start with a piece of [code (Coliru)](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/66f46bf42c34a887):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

struct A
{
    thread_local static A* p_a;
    thread_local static int i;
};

thread_local int A::i;
thread_local A* A::p_a;

int main( )
{
    A::p_a = new A;

    auto lambda = [](A* a)
        {
          a->i = 1; // Prints 1 (below, of course)
          std::cout << a->i << std::endl;
        };

    std::thread t(std::bind(lambda, A::p_a));
    t.join();

    // Prints 0 (it hasn't been modified)
    std::cout << A::p_a->i << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

As all of you can see, the second thread modifies its thread local copy of `A::i`, even though I accessed it from another thread local object of another thread. Is it the expected behaviour? Because it makes impossible to get info from another thread using a "referer" unless I pass a pointer or reference to the foreign's thread_local object which I want to read.

With "referer" I refer something which manages or can give you access to its own thread_local variable from its thread. But that's impossible!! Any expression yielding a thread_local variable, no matter from whom (I have done different test, even with accessor functions), ends by using the thread_local instance of the reading thread.

Comment: I am not sure using a `thread_local` to communicate between threads is a in keeping with the spirit of `thread_local` storage. Why not just use a normal `static`?

Comment: I'm just.... "understanding the behaviour" (or trying to).

Comment: Ah well its a *syntax* issue. Just because you are using syntax that looks like you are dereferencing an `A` pointer, you're not. The compiler sees it is a `static` and ignores the pointer and goes straight for the single (per thread in this case) static instance. The whole `thread_local` business is actually irrelevant to that.

Comment: Make i a regular non static and non thread_local member. Then your lambda will be referring to the i from the instance of A created in main.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a syntax issue: In this case `a->i;` is ***identical*** to `A::i;` because `A::i` is a *static member* and its address is not dependant on any one instance of `A`.

So just because you are using syntax that looks like you are dereferencing an `A` pointer, you're not. The compiler sees it is a *static member* and ignores the pointer and goes straight for the single (per thread in this case) `static` instance. The whole `thread_local` business is actually irrelevant to that.

So when you are accessing a *static member* of `A` through `A* a` in your *lambda*, the compiler is ignoring the *address* you gave it and doing `A::i` regardless (getting its own `thread_local` version).

```
struct A
{
    static int i;
};

A* a = new A;
a->i; // identical to A::i (because i is static)
```

This is standard syntax as mentioned here in the **C++14 Standard**:

> **5.2.5** Class member access **[** expr.ref **]**
>
> **1.** A postfix expression followed by a dot . or an arrow ->, optionally followed by the keyword template (14.2),
>   and then followed by an id-expression, is a postfix expression. The postfix expression before the dot or arrow
>   is evaluated; <sup>**65**</sup> the result of that evaluation, together with the id-expression, determines the result of the
>   entire postfix expression.
>
> ...
>
> <sup>**65)**</sup> If the class member access expression is evaluated, the subexpression evaluation happens even if the result is unnecessary
>   to determine the value of the entire postfix expression, for example ***if the id-expression denotes a static member***.

(emphasis mine)

Comment: But that's a "compiler" thing? Or is it present on the standard?

Comment: @Peregring-lk Its part of the syntax. If you think about it there is only **one** version of static members per class. So how can the compiler care about which address you access that **single** instance? With `thread_local` it simply means there is only one *per thread* but the problem remains. Accessing *static* members through `->` doesn't use the pointer, it just uses the *class type* to find the static (or thread_local static) instance.

Comment: Yes.  my comment deleted as obsolete.  This one will follow shortly.

Comment: Yes its clearer. I was just wondering if you replied because of your "own deductions" or that's the "designed" behaviour. Thinks that the dereference operator is being ignored; it is just seen to track which object the expression refers to; it's like searching "by name". Thinks that "p_a" could be a custom made pointer wrapper with an overloaded `operator*` and so on; the "syntax sugar" explanation will be harder to defend (what if there's an `if` involved before returning the reference?). But anyway, in any case, I'm convinced the used var will be the thread local one and no the external one.

Comment: @Peregring-lk I just included an excerpt from the `C++14 Standard` confirming this syntax is legal when accessing *static members*. Regarding overloading `operator->` well that just yields another pointer to which the `->` is finally applied. I would imagine (though not confirmed) the type of the yielded pointer determines which class' static member is accessed in that case.

Answer (score 0):

you passed one 'A' porinter, but we should know that 'i' variable and 'p_a' variable are not belong 'A' actually, then are static, so although you started a thread passed by a 'A' pointer,then modified 'i' variable, it is different ,because this 'i' is not outside 'i',they are different.